# Using NSIS, How can the user modify it to contain more than 8192Bytes?

Tags: nsis

Thanks for reading my article :]

I received a response using http communication, but it was upgraded because it is more than 1024 bytes. So, the Byte of ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} became 8192. However, an error occurs because the return value of Json type that I receive exceeds 8192 bytes. What setting should I set to get more bytes?

Comment: Is the entire file too large or does it contain a single value that is too large?

Comment: Example : [{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"},{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"},{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"}] <- Can take !                                

Example (Can No) : [{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"},{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"},{"Return":"1", "Out":"Any Request"}] * 1000 ( Over 8192Byte ) <- Error And Exit                               

dll and get it in the form of char*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the entire JSON in a NSIS string, you must use the plug-in to find the values you need:

This is able to parse more than 9000 bytes:

```
!macro prepare_example
FileOpen $1 "$temp\!tempjson.txt" w
FileWrite $1 "["
${For} $3 1 500
    ${IfThen} $3 U> 1 ${|} FileWrite $1 "," ${|}
    FileWrite $1 '{"Return":"$3", "Out":"Any Request"}$\n'
${Next}
FileWrite $1 "]"
FileSeek $1 0 END $2
FileClose $1
DetailPrint "About to parse $2 bytes of JSON..."
!macroend

!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
!insertmacro prepare_example

ClearErrors
nsJSON::Set /file "$temp\!tempjson.txt"
${IfThen} ${Errors} ${|} Abort "nsJSON::Set failed" ${|}
nsJSON::Get /count /end
${IfThen} ${Errors} ${|} Abort "nsJSON::Get failed" ${|}
Pop $1
DetailPrint Count=$1
${IfThen} $1 <> 0 ${|} IntOp $1 $1 - 1 ${|}
${For} $3 0 $1
    nsJSON::Get /index $3 /end
    ${IfThen} ${Errors} ${|} Abort "nsJSON::Get failed" ${|}
    Pop $2
    DetailPrint Object=$2
${Next}

${For} $3 0 $1
    nsJSON::Get /index $3 "Return" /end
    ${IfThen} ${Errors} ${|} Abort "nsJSON::Get failed" ${|}
    Pop $2
    DetailPrint Object.Return=$2
${Next}
SectionEnd
```